# rsyntaxtextarea component add netbeans

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting, rsyntaxtextarea

I'm using `rsyntaxtextarea` , i've added it to Netbeans palette, here it has two components,

> An RSyntaxTextArea is the main text editor class. It extends
>   JTextArea, so it has all the standard methods you'd expect from a
>   Swing text component, plus more specific to handling syntax
>   highlighting.
>
> An RTextScrollPane is an extension of JScrollPane that supports line
>   numbers. You can use a standard JScrollPane if you want, but when
>   editing source code, it is often nice to have line numbering enabled.

I can actually add `RSyntaxTextArea` by dragging and dropping it from palette, but i cannot do that for `RTextScrollPane` (it is necessary for `RSyntaxTextArea` to feel better than existing scroll panel). The error message says that the component cannot be instantiated and that you should make sure it is a JavaBean

> How can i add these two components in netbeans through drag & drop ?

Comment: Is `RTextScrollPane` on the `Palette` under `Swing Containers`?

Comment: @trashgod ya, i've added it through tools->palette->Swing/AWT Components

Comment: If that solves the problem, you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @trashgod No, even if i've added it to palette, i can't add it through drag & drop,  i've added RSyntaxTextArea  though, even i've added RTextScrollPane through custom code in it, but i couldn't see that in Inspector or in Application ....i donnot what to do, BTW i didnt add it to swing containers, i've added it to a new category

Comment: @trashgod i doesn't matter where it is right? i've added it to Swing containers also, but no luck

Comment: I was hoping it had been installed automatically and just hidden in another sub-menu

Comment: @trashgod is there another way of adding to palette? other than adding from jar file?

Comment: Not that I know. Edit: I might be worth asking in a Netbeans forum.

Answer (score 0):

//   Try it;

```
/**
 *
 * @author Filipe
 */
public class RTextScrollPaneFlp extends RTextScrollPane {

    public RTextScrollPaneFlp() {

        super(new RTextEditorSyntaxFlp());
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @author Filipe
 */
public class RTextEditorSyntaxFlp extends RSyntaxTextArea {

    public RTextEditorSyntaxFlp() {

        super(5, 20);

        this.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_SQL);

        this.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);

        Color azulClaro = Color.decode("#E0EEEE");

        this.setCurrentLineHighlightColor(azulClaro);

    }

}


/*Then right click on the class RTextScrollPaneFlp->Tools->Add to palette.

Create a new category or add the default category "beans".

Done, your component will appear in the palette, I hope that helps.

Enjoy yourself!
```

*/